# Git rebase: generate TODO then proceed later

Tags: git, rebase

Is there a way to perform an interactive such as:

1. Make Git generate the `git-rebase-todo` file
2. Pause the rebase process
3. Edit `git-rebase-todo` out-process
   (e.g. using a local IDE
   )
4. Eventually proceed with rebasing given contents of `git-rebase-todo`.

The reason I want to do this is that we have implemented a remote git console over the web which just delegates commands to a local git process and we'd like to be able to perform interactive rebases remotely. We had to do this b/c in our work environment we are forced to have a remote working directory and Git is much too slow over the network.

---

EDIT:

I found an approach that works more or less, which is to set `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` to a script that pipes the `git-rebase-todo` content
to a file and exits with an error code to abort the rebase process. I could edit the todo file, then set `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` to a process that rewrites `git-rebase-todo` with the content of the edited file and exits with `0`, letting git proceed with the rebase process.

However, I had not realized how often git then delegates back the control to the editor depending on the changes made to the todo list and that makes it very impractical to approach the problem the way I wanted.

I haven't had time to investigate further, but probably that I'd need to maintain a persistent reference to the `cmd` process to mimic a console session
and somehow find a way to intercept editor calls with a waiting process that signals back to the web UI that an editor should be shown. Upon closing the web UI editor the front-end would signal back that the edit action took place and the waiting editor process could exit with a status `0`.

Not sure that's possible to implement, I'll investigate further when I have more time...

Comment: Maybe not helpful in your case, but I'll put it out there anyway: If the only purpose of the rebase is to squash commits, you can use `--autosquash` mode to avoid opening `git-rebase-todo` in the first place: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/autosquashing-git-commits

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using whatever tool you will use to generate *the real todo* as the editor? Git could not care less for what the editor will be

You could do something like:

```
GIT_EDITOR=/usr/bin/ourtool git rebase -i blahblah
```

My hunch is that /usr/bin/ourtool will be called with the todo file as the argument.... then you can modify whatever content is there in the file while running ourtool... exit with 0 when you are done and rebase should start with *your* instructions.

Comment: I want to avoid the rebase process waiting after another process to proceed. Ideally I'd want to be able to edit `git-rebase-todo` using an IDE on my local machine, then invoke `git rebase --continue` or something in the remote console.

Comment: FYI - I added more precisions to the question if that sparks some ideas.